# jquery display floating div

Tags: jquery

When the user hovers over a specific element, I wish to display a div (up and to the right) that they can click to popup a dialog. The div would appear almost like a tooltip. The div would disappear when they hover away.

Comment: Which part exactly do you have a problem with? Could post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your exact code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link you're looking for.
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

It's a really handy tooltip plugin that I've used multiple times.
It's easy to modify and to extend for whatever your particular needs might be.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to quickly make your own for only one location, it is easy to do.

jquery code:

```
$('[id$=idOfElement]').mouseover(function () {
    $('[id$=divToShow]').show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('[id$=divToShow]').hide();
});
```

html:

`<div ID="div_Tooltip" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:0; left:100px;">
      Content to Show
</div>`

All you have to do is absolutely position the div for exactly where you want it to pop up.
However, if you are going to have several tooltips on a page, I would use a plugin such as the one JimP recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can code this yourself pretty easily with a combination of `.hover();` and CSS

```
$("div.someclass").hover(function(){
    $("div.someclass div.tooltip").show(); //or use fade in
}, function(){
    $("div.someclass div.tooltip").hide(); //or use fade out
});
```

Assuming you don't wish to use the plugin described in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery [ClueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) plugin, it is capable of handling the functionality you're looking for